# AngularJS : get datas from (api rest)Symfony's url result

Tags: angularjs, rest, symfony

I am trying to retrieve datas from my Restful api symfony with AngularJS, but i get this error "*Error: [$http:badreq] Http request configuration url must be a string or a $sce trusted object*".

Here is my Symfony controller :

```
$agent = $this->get('doctrine')
        ->getRepository('CERAgentBundle:Agent', 'agent')
        ->findByCode($employeeID);

    $session = new Session();
    $session->set('agent', $agent);

    $formatted = [
        'civilite' => $agent[0]->getCivilite(),
        'prenom' => $agent[0]->getPrenom(),
        'nom' => $agent[0]->getNom(),
        ];

    return $formatted;
}
```

that give me : 
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYGBv.png)

Here is my AngularJS controller :

```
angular.module('frontProfilDeveloppementApp')
.controller('AboutCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $sce){
  var url = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl('http://localhost:8000/index');
  $http.get({
      method:'GET',
      url:url})
      .success(function (data) {
          $scope.result = data;
      });
```

});

My Angular view :

```
<div ng-app="frontProfilDeveloppementApp" ng-controller="AboutCtrl">

<p>Today's welcome message is:</p>

<h1>{{result.nom}}</h1>
```

Thanks for help

Comment: Why not just do: `$http.get(url).then(function(res){})` ?

Comment: Thank you all for answering, i written a new angular controller based on you answers and i face new errors : "Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8000/index. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing)." I know i have to add headers (i will have to do it from angular).

Answer (score 0):

Looking over the documentation for [SCE](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce), it appears that you're not using it for its intended use. SCE is more for rendering raw html/css into the DOM from a trusted source without having it parsed for vulnerabilities since it's treated as trusted. In the case of the URL, you'd use SCE to bind it safely somewhere in a template, but your use case doesn't seem appropriate, why not just use a string?

If anything, you probably want to use SCE for the actual content retrieved, not the URL used to retrieve the content itself.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what version of Angular you're using but success is deprecated and your parameters are not valid for a $http.get request. Your code should be something like:

```
angular.module('frontProfilDeveloppementApp')
.controller('AboutCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $sce){
  var url = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl('http://localhost:8000/index');
  $http.get(url})
      .then(function (data) {
          $scope.result = data;
      });
});
```